# A way to concatenate Console.Beep sounds

Tags: c#, audio, beep

I've been playing around with some C# and specifically making sounds... [because it's fun](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/visual-studio-tfs-2013-%E2%80%93-list). So I've got it all working but there's something bugging me to do with `Console.Beep()`: it doesn't directly concatenate sounds. For example, running the code below will result in a series of 250-millisecond bursts of sound - but instead of all being run together and sounding as if they are one, they become disjointed, with a ~50ms pause in between each sound.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    Console.Beep(980, 250);
}
```

So the question is, is there any **programmatic** way to make the system run the sounds together? I have to say I don't really expect there to be but I figured it was worth an ask, since many [other](http://blog.filipekberg.se/2013/12/16/making-sound-using-c/) [resources](http://inphamousdevelopment.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/console-beep-for-64-bit-windows/) seem to just accept the fact that it doesn't.

Comment: `Console.Beep` is not part of C#

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Wasn't aware. Thanks for the edit

Comment: The C# programming language and the .NET Framework are two different things.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - so I see

Comment: More fun (but doesn't answer your question) http://stackoverflow.com/q/3319959/397817

Comment: It is quite doubtful that your ear is fine-tuned enough to exactly measure a 50 msec interval.  It is however extraordinary sensitive to any *interruption* in a tone.  That generates many harmonics that you hear clearly.  Console.Beep() is very unsuitable to create structured sound, play with your sound card.

Comment: @HansPassant: I said *roughly*... I doubt it's actually 50ms but it seemed around that by comparing it with a supposedly 250ms sound.

Comment: What about creating some threads and running this code in each of them?

Comment: @qamyoncu: How does that help?

Comment: @ArtOfCode Just a thought. Can't you start 3 threads and loop through 0 to 4 with msleep(500)? It may need some synchronization for sure..

Comment: @qamyoncu Not sure I get how you mean. What effect does that threading have on the concatenation of the sounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, that method uses kernel's functions. I will prove:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
[HostProtection(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, UI = true)]
public static void Beep(int frequency, int duration)
{
    if (frequency < 37 || frequency > 32767)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("frequency", frequency, Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_BeepFrequency", new object[]
        {
            37,
            32767
        }));
    }
    if (duration <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("duration", duration, Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedPosNum"));
    }
    Win32Native.Beep(frequency, duration);
}
```

This is the `Console.Beep`'s code, it uses `Win32Native.Beep` to actually perform beep (Aside from the checks above it), and that method leads to:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool Beep(int frequency, int duration);
```

A function that imported from kernel.

Unless you hard-code and modify your kernel, you can't. (Which I am sure you don't want to)

I can give you an alternative: http://naudio.codeplex.com/, you can instead control your sound by using this tool and giving it stream. (You can create stream that don't use file as source)